# why `OnWorkerEvent` is used in `wxProgressDialog`?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have to display a progress bar using `wxWidgets`. Currently I am doing this :

```
    m_dlgProgress = new wxGenericProgressDialog(wxString("Heading"), wxString("Message"), max, this, wxPD_APP_MODAL | wxPD_AUTO_HIDE | wxPD_SMOOTH);
    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++)
    {
    cont = m_dlgProgressConfig->Update(i);
    i += max / 7;
    wxMilliSleep(200);
    }
    callingSomeFunctionFromBackend();
    //after this function is executed I am updating dialogue with its maximum value
    cont = m_dlgProgressConfig->Update(max);
```

Is this correct way to display progress bar? I have seen some codes which create a thread and use OnWorkerEvent to update progress bar. Why do they create a thread. What I have done is correct or will it cause any problem further?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is mostly fine, although you should really create the dialog on stack and not allocate it on the heap (especially without ever deleting it) and it's not clear why do you use `wxGenericProgressDialog` instead of `wxProgressDialog`.

But using a separate thread is preferable because it keeps your program GUI responsive while in your example it will be blocked for 200ms at a time and also for however long "some function from backend" is going to take. If this is acceptable for you, you can keep it like this, but using a background thread often results in a better user experience -- even though it requires more effort from the programmer.

Comment: Yes, I will creata a thread then. and how should I create dialogue on stack?

Comment: Just create it as `wxProgressDialog dlg("Heading", "Message", max)` instead of using `new` to create it on the heap.

Comment: can you please help me with this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894040/create-wxthread-to-call-backend-function-for-every-evt-treelist-item-expanded